# What is the best design decision approach?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design, abstract-class

I have two classes (named `MyFoo1` and `MyFoo2`) that share some common functionality. So far, it does not seem like I need any polymorphic inheritance but, at this point, I am considering the following options:

1. Have the common functionality in a utility class. Both of these classes call these methods from that utility class.
2. Have an abstract class and implement common methods in that abstract class. Then, the `MyFoo1` and `MyFoo2` classes will derive from that abstract class.

Any suggestion on what would be the best design decision?

Comment: @DanielA.White - Programmers is for questions about the field, etc. Architectural questions still belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: The reason you are getting vague answers is because you have obfuscated what `Foo1` and `Foo2` are in your question. i.e. it is not clear whether they are specialisations of the same thing. Can you tell us more about them?

Comment: @Sohnee: I realized that also but I think I have got my answer from Justin. Thanks for your help as well

Comment: @JustinNiessner Please check the FAQ before giving incorrect advice. Software architecture is indeed considered on-topic on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @S.Robins - But it also valid on StackOverflow where the question was asked and seems a better fit for architecture style questions. This is one of the downsides to having overlap between the two.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Clearly the question has been migrated here, months ago it seems, so my comment may have appeared late. Given it was migrated *from* SO, it seems the moderators feel it is a better match for Programmers, which I'd tend to agree with. And again, the FAQ makes it clear that architectural questions are definitely on topic on Programmers... overlaps notwithstanding ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are `Foo1` and `Foo2` actually related (conceptually, that is) or do they simply share some functionality?

If they're conceptually related, I would go with an abstract class.

If they simply share the functionality, I would break out that functionality and make a separate class. You can then use composition to build `Foo1` and `Foo2`.

Comment: Each of these two classes interface with a third party library to fulfill a unique functionality. In some cases they use third party library in same way; in other each of it has own way of calling and processing response from same third party library.

Comment: If that's the case, then I would wrap the 3rd party library in a utility class or interface and provide the common functionality to the classes that way. This allows you to change out 3rd party libraries and enforce the boundary between the external dependency and your code.

Comment: That's it. In the end the question when doing a design decision should always be, "What will be easier to read?" (or "What would another person find easier to understans?" if you want)

Answer (score 3):

As always it depends.

If all instaces of `Foo1` and `Foo2` can logically be called `FooParent` then use inheritance.

For the utility class to make sense it should be something that be used across multiple projects, think about the Apache libraries on this one.

Typically in these scenarios you want to have `Foo1` and `Foo2` be composed of `FooUtility`.

Answer (score 1):

As the other posters stated it is difficult to answer the question without knowing the relationship between the classes. The answer is, as always, it depends.

Inheritance should really only be used if you can say "Foo1 *is a* FooParent". Inheritance is a powerful tool, but it can also tie your hands down the road.

The GoF recommended "composition over inheritance" - using interfaces allows for maximum flexibility. The downside is that you can end up with code bloat if you declare an interface for every little responsibility. Interfaces generally describe what an object *does* instead of what it *is* (inheritance).

Theory aside, is the common functionality key to what Foo1 and Foo2 are or do? Or is it more boilerplate code that you'd like to not have to write every time. If it is part of the class behavior, use inheritance. If not, if it's just boilerplate (data access code, validation or security) then a utility class would probably be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I feel that the two classes Foo1 and Foo2 have no business relationship(because you have specified that you do not need any polymorphic inheritance).

so based on that I would suggest you to use some external Utility class rather than adding an abstract super class. Since relating two classes which are not really related just to share common functionality could compromise/complicate the future expansions of your project.

For example if you have some Foo11 and Foo12 which has business relationship to Foo1 it would be simpler and more logical to use common parent Foo1Parent at that point.

Answer (score 0):

As you said --

> ... that share some common functionality. So far it does not seem like I
>   need any polymorphic inheritance ...

Which means that, you can encapsulate the common functionality. From my experience, most of the time, encapsulation is better than inheritance.

```
class Myclass{
   private Common common;

}
```

I am not saying Inheritance is bad. It has its own place.

Comment: but what about `class Tomato extends Fruit { //... oh no all my properties are like vegetables.  }`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your design is such that each class has clear responsibilities which can clearly be described by their names.  Consider which modularization will produce code that is easiest to test and modify. Factoring out whatever common code to a class called `Utilities` is a code smell.